# how can I remove command delimiter from my domain list?

Tags: bash

I am trying create a sets of subdomain folders based for each data for manangment , and other stuff like `ssl` , but how can I remove command delimiter to send `$host` as a single domain?

```
HOSTS=domain.io,www.domain.io,api.domain.io,app.domain.io
for host in $HOSTS; do
    mkdir -p "letsencrypt/live/${host}/fullchain.pem"
done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `IFS` (Internal Field Separator) to break on `','` or `'\n'`, e.g

```sh
#!/bin/bash

oifs="$IFS"     ## save original IFS (default " \t\n", space, tab, newline)
IFS=$',\n'      ## set IFS to break on comma or newline

HOSTS=domain.io,www.domain.io,api.domain.io,app.domain.io

for host in $HOSTS; do
    ## mkdir -p "letsencrypt/live/${host}/fullchain.pem"
    echo "mkdir -p letsencrypt/live/${host}/fullchain.pem"
done

IFS="$oifs"     ## restore original IFS if needed for later commands
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ bash domains.sh
mkdir -p letsencrypt/live/domain.io/fullchain.pem
mkdir -p letsencrypt/live/www.domain.io/fullchain.pem
mkdir -p letsencrypt/live/api.domain.io/fullchain.pem
mkdir -p letsencrypt/live/app.domain.io/fullchain.pem
```

Uncomment the command and remove the `echo` to actually create the domains. Set `IFS="$oifs"` to restore the original `IFS` (if needed).

Comment: Also note, I believe letsencrypt supports wildcard domains now, so you may be able to create a certificate for `*domain.io`. You will need to check the documentation on their site.

Comment: sure, but the problems with `wildcard domains` is people can request on ahaha.domain.io or xyy.domain.io which are valid, but I want to only issue for only pretty specific domains

Comment: I knew there was a reason I never used them `:)`